# Continuous/infinite horizontal scroll on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I have a shelf which when you hover the left or right buttons scrolls left and right. However, at the moment this only scrolls a defined amount.. and this shelf will be populated via lazy loading, so there is no real way of knowing how wide the shelf is.

Sure, I could set the number to 99999999 and the animation speed to a similarly high number, but surely there's a smarter way to do it? Without plug-ins!

Thanks for the help..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3mPw/)

```
$('.scroll-arrow').each(function(){
    var modifier = ($(this).hasClass('right')) ? 1 : -1;
    var sib = ('.shelf-slide');
    var sl = 0;

    $(this).hover(function() {
        sl = $(this).siblings(sib).scrollLeft();
        $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
        $(this).siblings(sib).animate({scrollLeft: sl + (modifier * 1000)}, 5000, 'linear');
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
    });
});
```

Comment: something like this? [http://jsfiddle.net/A3mPw/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/A3mPw/7/)

Comment: Perfect. Great work. If you reply as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function to keep animating while you hover the arrow like this

```
function animatecontent(ele,modifier){//function to scroll
  var sl = ele.scrollLeft();
  //120 should be the width of the ".content" and 500 the time to scroll 1 ".content"
  ele.animate({scrollLeft: sl + (modifier * 120)}, 500, 'linear',function(){
        if(hover){//on callback if it is still hover call the same function
            animatecontent(ele,modifier);
        }
    });
};
var hover=false;
$('.scroll-arrow').each(function(){
    var modifier = ($(this).hasClass('right')) ? 1 : -1;
    var sib = ('.shelf-slide');
    $(this).hover(function() {
        hover=true;
    $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
      animatecontent($(this).siblings(sib),modifier);//pass the element to animate and the modifier     
    }, function() {
        hover=false;
        $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3mPw/7/

Comment: Thanks for also explaining.